# How to get an excerpt from a text

Tags: json, python-3.x, corda

How can I bring a snippet of a text. I have a file and I need to get it from the "config sys interfaces" section until the first "end". The best way to do this would be to use regex?

```
#config-version=FGVM64-5.6.3-FW-build1547-171204:opmode=0:vdom=0:user=bruno
#conf_file_ver=153884383284212
#buildno=1547
#global_vdom=1
config system global
    set admin-scp enable
    set admintimeout 100
    set alias "FortiGate-VM64"
    set hostname "000-1001-0"
    set timezone 18
end
**config system interface    <---------- Start
    edit "port1"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.0.150 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh http telnet
        set type physical
        set role wan
        set snmp-index 1
    next
    edit "port2"
        set vdom "root"
        set type physical
        set role wan
        set snmp-index 2
    next
end                       <------------ Stop**
config firewall schedule recurring
    edit "always"
        set day sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday
    next
    edit "none"
    next
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The result should be:

```
config system interface 
    edit "port1"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.0.150 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh http telnet
        set type physical
        set role wan
        set snmp-index 1
    next
    edit "port2"
        set vdom "root"
        set type physical
        set role wan
        set snmp-index 2
    next
end
```